# Prioritize whitelist LAN Connections

Tags: bitcoind

With bitcoind I have whitelisted local connections with `whitelist=10.0.0.0/8` in bitcoin.conf on my server. When I launch bitcoin-qt on my laptop (only has one peer the server) it does not sync any blocks unless I block all incoming connections from the WAN to the server.

I have used `bitcoin-cli -netinfo` and seen that my client `10.0.0.10` is listed as `npr` so I know it is connected.

I have seen the suggestion to use `whitebind` but that requires more effort to implement than just using `whitelist`. [Reserve the connection for local wallets](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/38537/reserve-the-connection-for-local-wallets/38546#38546)

Is there a way to give priority to whitelisted clients so they can sync immediately or is whitebind the only option?

Comment: How do you connect the local client? Addnode?

Comment: connect=10.0.0.1:8333